# Error Handling in a POST Request in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am following the guide at official Angular documentation at https://angular.io/guide/http. 
The handleError function in the post request has 2 arguments and it's giving me an error of 'expected 1 argument but got 2'.

The code for error handling is:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

The code for the post request is:

```
/** POST: add a new hero to the database */
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

Does the function need no argument in any case?
I think it's trying to call the function again with the argument of hero in case of error. Is that so?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you pass in two parameters to `handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse)` when it expects just one?

Comment: It's what's in there. I am not passing the arguments. That's the code provided there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular guide is actually wrong/confusing on this, or at least, they did not show the right examples. When you do something like this:

```
catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
```

The `handleError` should accept two parameters, and also return a function which accepts one parameter. So something like this:

```
handleError<T>(action: string, object: T): (e: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable<never> {
  return (e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }

    return throwError(
      `Something bad happened while performing action: ${action}, on object ${object}`
    );
  };
}
```

If you want the `handleError` be like the one you have:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }

  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.'
  );
};
```

You should change the way you pass this into the `catchError`:

```
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleError(error));
```

If you are not accessing the `this` context from the `handleError` you can do the following:

```
catchError(this.handleError)
```

In this [part](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) of the guide, it's explained better. It's just that the examples in the POST and PUT sections are missing the correct implementation of the `handleError` method

Comment: So the two parameters are only to print in what function and what object the error occurred?

Comment: Exactly. But usually you already have access to the variables. So this method is not used a lot.

Comment: Makes sense, I was wondering the exact same thing when reading the Angular POST example.